# Using GIMP to open .xcf files fails

Tags: wine, gimp

Version 2.9.5 in Ubuntu 14.04 ;
After saving an image in xcf format, I try to open it with GIMP version 2.8.18 on wine or Windows

This gives me an error message:

> Opening 'C:\users\kisame\Bureau\2.9.5.xcf' failed:
>   XCF error: unsupported XCF file version 8 encountered

Is there a solution or do I need to change version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, at this stage you may want to use GIMP 2.9 for testing purposes only.  It is a pre-release version.

The reason you're getting this message is most likely that you are using features of the XCF format that aren't compatible with older versions of GIMP, such as higher bit depths.  It is hard to say exactly what feature in particular that is in any given case.

It's possible that once GIMP 2.9 is released the behaviour may change, such as getting better warnings and messages when you are saving something which may be incompatible with older versions.

Comment: True there is an option Add your to control more compatible with older versions. In save as ..
I used the save after Completion